# jquery optimize looped animate function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, each, setinterval

I'm needing to find a more efficient way of accomplishing this outcome:

http://jsfiddle.net/H4sjf/1/

The `setInterval()` mixed with the `.each()` and subsequent `.animate()` makes this script considerably slow.  Is there a way to accomplish this outcome utilizing some other 'less expensive' process/functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setinterval maybe you could create a callback function for animate() that re-animates "this" and calls itself as a callback?

[**edit**]
I removed a bit of unnecessary code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8kgAB/1/

```
DoPopulateSoundBoard();
function DoPopulateSoundBoard(){
    $('.sound-syn-column').each(function(){
        var dSoundSyn = '';
        for( i = 0; i <= 8; i++ ){
                dSoundSyn += "<div class='ui-corner-all sound-syn'></div>";
            }
        $(this).append( dSoundSyn + "<div class='sound-syn-cover'></div>" );
    });




        $('.sound-syn-cover').each(function(){
                    test34($(this));
        });

}

function test34(obj){
    obj.animate({height: Math.floor( Math.random()*56) }, 500, function(){
            test34($(obj));
    });       
}
```

not sure if this is any faster, but it might be since setinterval is so slow.

Comment: please , research what is inside of `this` when it is inside `$(..)each(function(){ console.log(this) })` .. -1

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, `this` when inside of `$(...)each(function(){ //this })` refers to the object currently being processed by each... which would explain why my code functions properly. what are you trying to say? can you explain to me what I've done wrong?

Comment: @tereško I ran console.log($(this)) inside of the each() callback, and it logged the element that was being animated, which is exactly what we wanted to pass to the function. can you explain what I've done wrong so I can update the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can decouple `setInterval()` and `.each()` by adding individual `setInterval()` functions to each `div` just once:

```
$('.sound-syn-cover').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('intervalCallback', setInterval(function(){
        $this.animate({height: Math.floor( Math.random()*56) }, 500);
    }, 300));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4sjf/3/)